# Laravel routes not working.

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-routing

Trying to get started with Laravel. Going through a simple tutorial (I thought) and they have this going through the route.php page.

```
Route::controller(Controller::detect());
Route::get('about', 'home@about');
```

I also have a simple login.php page thats not working

```
<?php

class Login_Controller extends Base_Controller{

    public function action_index()
    {
        echo 'test';
    }

}

?>
```

It seems like anything I create it will not show up. It just gives a 404 error. Do I need to flush something? I tried restarting Apache but no luck.

Do I need Composer if so how would I set up the .json? and where would I put it

Comment: Is it an Apache 404 error or the Laravel 404 error? If it's Apache you might need to enable `mod_rewrite`. Also, you should be omitting the closing `?>` for PHP, this prevents any unnecessary white space making it through and causing header errors.

Comment: Its an Apache 404 error ..mod_rewrite should be turned on..and I made the change in application.php to reflect that. But I will go double check the configuration page

Answer (score 1):

`Route::controller()` should always come last because this will specify a number of wildcard routes, and routes following it may then not get caught.

```php
Route::get('about', 'home@about');
Route::controller(Controller::detect());
```

Having said that, I would always encourage you to specify your controllers manually.  Using `Controller::detect()` means that **all** controllers will be routed, including base controllers.

Remember that in Laravel you should *return* content from views, not echo directly.  So for your login controller try this instead...

```
function action_index()
{
    return 'test';
}
```

This should (if you have apache configured correctly) respond to `http://mysite.com/login` and `http://mysite.com/login/index`, if neither of these work try adding `index.php` in the address, like `http://mysite.com/index.php/login`.

Comment: you mentioned if I have apache configured correctly? What do I need to check? I believe I enabled mod_rewrite and made the change in application.php..but i didnt change anything in my host file so I should still be using //ServerIP/WebAPP/public <--gets me home page..anything else I use gets me nothing..I am using a local server with Ubuntu SSH if that helps

Comment: What happens when you visit `//ServerIP/WebAPP/public/index.php/login`?

Comment: I am not in front of my development machine I will report when I get back to it. Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: ....it works lol with public/index.php/login . How do I edit my apache config file on Ubuntu whats the command ?

Comment: If `public/index.php/login` works then PHP is set up right, but you're not rewriting.  There are many things that could be wrong in that case, especially if you've configured apache yourself.  Start by confirming that mod_rewrite is enabled and that overrides are allowed. There's a good [how to htaccess](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html) from apache.org